# How to arrange images in different drawable folders?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I know the discussion about this is available everywhere and I myself have worked with these folders, but still after reading them I recently I had a big confusion regarding how to arrange images in drawable folders -

Look at this XML File -

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/wallpaper_chapter_selection"
    tools:context="com.greenloop.joindotsandpaint.ChapterSelection">

    <ImageView android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent"
         android:scaleType="centerInside"
         android:src="@drawable/img2"
         android:padding="20dp" />

<RelativeLayout
```

Let's consider 2 phones regarding this **Landscape Mode** -

Nexus 10 - 2560 px * 1600px   **xhdpi**

Nexus 5 - 1920px * 1080px  **xxhdpi**

In the case of Nexus 10 - Image size will be 1600px (height)
And in the case of Nexus 5 - Image size will be 1080px

Image size required by Nexus 10 will be greater than that required by Nexus 5, But nexus 10 will take image from the xhdpi folder (smaller image size) as it is xhdpi
and nexus 5 will take image from xxhdpi folder.

So how should I work around this. I have lots of similar layouts in which I am facing a similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-xxhdpi` etc. specifies only the dpi dimension and devices of all sizes are going to get resources from the same folder as long as they have the same dpi specifications. To add the screen size dimension you can add `large` (for devices 7" and around), `xlarge`(for devices 10" and around) etc. to this. For example you can have a `drawable-xlarge-xhdpi` to force the Nexus 10" to get a particular resource from this folder. Or your can have only `drawable-xlarge` and this way all the 10" devices will pull the resources from this folder, no matter what their dpi is.
Basically the one-catch-all is the `drawable` folder and you overwrite on a case by case basis with the values from `drawable-*-*-etc`. folders.

Comment: I also see, developer create "drawable" folder and putting image inside it. Can you also put this in your answer?

Comment: So how should I really arrange images. Can you please elaborate. Should I put images of same pixels but different ppi in different drawables or what should I do. Please elaborate with one good solution ! Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no one answer that fits everything. It very much depend on what you are trying to accomplish with each image. If for example you are using an image and your intention is to keep it the same physical size (let's say for a button or imagebutton), then probably your best bet is to put the set into drawable-**dpi folders. If your intention is to have them appear in different sizes (bigger for bigger screen sizes) you probably need to put them in the drawable + drawable-**large folders at least. Personally I make this decision on a case by case basis.

Comment: @mubeen - I didn't mean to have a complete reference of all the possible folders and combinations, but I was rather trying to point out the mechanism. The `drawable` folder is a special case, however, and I updated my answer to reference it.

Answer (score 1):

Check the part under "Screen size":

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html

You can (or rather need to) create different layouts for different screen sizes. Phones and tablets are treated differently.

The Nexus 5 has a higher DPI. 1080px on 5" VS 1600px on 10"... So it is correct that Nexus 5 uses the xxhdpi resource (here: image!) and Nexus 10 the xhdpi. (xhdpi isn't "bigger" than xxhdpi, it just "has less" pixel per inch).

Layouts for phones and tablets are something different to DPI of screens.

Comment: But, see the layout. I dont need to make different layouts for different screen size. I just want an image to be displayed on the whole screen. And it can be achieved through this particular layout only.